# Java/Scala lib to parse dot-notation to Json string

Tags: java, json, scala

I wanna parse some dot-notation map to a json string, for example I have:

```
input["top.second.third0"] = 0
input["top.second.third1"] = "hello"
```

And then I want to get the following json string from this map :

```
{"top":{
     "second":{
         "third0":0,
         "third1":"hello"
        }
   }
}
```

I know how to generate it by using split, I am asking if there is a Java/Scala library that can do that for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Play JSON, you can parse such expression to `JsPath` and then use it.

```
import play.api.libs.json._

val components = input.split("\\.")

components.headOption match {
  case Some(p) => components.tail.foldLeft(JsPath \ p) { _ \ _ }
  case _ => /* cannot parse */ ???
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do something like this to finish this task.

```
  val input = "a.b.c"
  val components = input.split("\\.")

  val jsPath = components.headOption match {
    case Some(p) => components.tail.foldLeft(JsPath \ p) { _ \ _ }
    case _ => /* cannot parse */ ???
  }
  val obj = JsPath.createObj(jsPath -> JsString("Hello"))
  Logger.debug("after write" + obj.toString)
```

I don't know why but seems everybody is using play if you use scala.